# java.lang.StackOverflowError while invoking downstream(SOAP/REST) in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

We are facing java.lang.StackOverflowError when invoking soap/rest service.
The issue is not seeing any downstream exception/error, but seeing close connection in logs and then getting stackoverflow error.

DEBUG testDmlcContainer-1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:79 - http-outgoing-17: Close connection
2017-01-25 00:50:15,861 DEBUG testDmlcContainer-1 org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway:339 
- failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
2017-01-25 00:50:15,862 DEBUG provDmlcContainer-1 org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:277 - preSend on channel 'testErrorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalState
Exception: Cannot process message,

The below piece is called in recursion, resulting in stackoverflow

org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHan
dler.java:105)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at ......

Comment: Please, consider to format your question properly : http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Also, please, study how to ask question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask